# AndroidでAdMobが表示されない

Tags: android, admob

http://nobuo-create.net/admob/
このサイトの通りにコードを組み立ててAdMobを表示しようとしましたが、
起動はできるのに何故か表示できません。
ゲームは完成しているのですが、AdMobの表示で四日程詰んでおります・・・
おかしい所や直す所を教えてください。どうかよろしくお願いします。

以下Adsense.javaのコードです

```
import jp.example.apuri.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public class Adsense extends Activity {
    LinearLayout layout_ad;
    AdView adView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"); //テスト用のUnitID
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        layout_ad = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ad);
        layout_ad.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        adView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adView.resume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

以下layoutの中のactivity_main.xmlのコードです

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="jp.example.apuri.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#999"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/layout_ad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

以下AndroidManifest.xmlのコードです

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jp.example.apuri"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<string android:name="アプリ名">Apurimei</string>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="jp.example.Apurimei.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

layout の中に`Adview`を記述していますが、それが、Java コード中の `layout_ad.addView(adView);`と矛盾しています。

まず、layout中の`Adview`を削除し、`android:id="@+id/layout_ad"`は`LinearLayout`に付けます。

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#999"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

これでどうでしょうか？

（また反対に、Java コードの方を使わずに、layout に任せてしまう方法も可能かと）